# Inherited Function Using Child Function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I was looking to have a base class and multiple child classes each with a separate implementations of one function used in many shared functions. This would be similar to this

```
class A {
    public:
    int a() {
        return 6;
    }
    int b() {
        return a() - 2;
    }
};

class B: public A {
    public:
    int a() {
        return 10;
    }
};

int main() {
    B x;
    std::cout << x.b() << std::endl;
}
```

How would I get `x.b()` to be `8` instead of `4`?

Comment: You most likely wanna look up what virtual functions are…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your function virtual,  so that `a()` always refers to the implementation of `a()` in the object's real class:

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual int a() {         //<<<<<<<<--------
        return 6;
    }
    int b() {
        return a() - 2;
    }
    virtual ~A() = default;  
};
```

In you version with a non-virtual function,  the body of `b()` calls the only `a()` it knows, which is the `A::a()`.

As a good practice, and to avoid nasty errors, when you define a virtual function indicate in the derived classes that you override the virtual function:

```
class B: public A {
    public:
    int a() override {
        return 10;
    }
};
```

Another good practice is also to foresee a virtual destructor in the base class.